# Recover LUKS LVM partition after overwriting partition table

Tags: data-recovery, gparted, partition-recovery, luks

I accidentally deleted the partition table of my hard disk in Gparted. The partition is an LVM encrypted with LUKS. I used "sudo hexdump /dev/sdb | grep LUKS" to find the LUKS header. When I then mounted it as a loop device using losetup, it was not recognised as a LUKS device. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXkTi.png)
[hexdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhBrN.png)
[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSI92.png)

Comment: Your hexdump does not show a LUKS header. You can try this guide (LUKS 2 only): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/741850/30851